# Call an embedded macro from VBA in access

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have a macro assigned to the onClick event of a button in a form. How can I call this macro programmatically?

I tried

```
btnName_Click
```

But this does not work since there is no function called `btnName_Click()` ... obviously :)

I can access the onClick Member via `Me.btnNewRecord.OnClick` but don't see a way to run the macro.

Comment: What would be the downside to converting it from an embedded to a named macro?  On the upside, you could then call it with `Docmd.RunMacro "YourMacroName"`

Comment: There is no real downside as far as I can see, for me it's just not as handy as working with embedded macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After extensive searching, I do not believe it is possible to reference the embedded macro, and run it. You can view the XML of the macro, but I know of no way of running it or even accessing it beyond it's XML stored as a string. A possible work around would be to convert all macros to VBA. To do this:

1. Open the form in design view.
2. Click Convert Form's Macros to Visual Basic

now you should be able to call the button's code with `btnName_Click` as you showed in your question.  Obviously if you did this, you would sacrifice the advantage of using macros (i.e. limited functionality without the user needing to trust your database).

---

Original Answer, which doesn't apply to Embedded Macros:

Use [DoCmd.RunMacro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192075.aspx)

Example:

```
Docmd.RunMacro(macroname)
```

where `macroname` is a string representing the name of the macro.

Comment: how can I figure out the name of the macro? The macro was auto-generated when I created the button.
edit: didn't see your edit... yes it's an Embedded Macro :-/

Comment: Thx for your effort! Now that I know the available options I can figure out another solution:)